# How do I get glog to use gflags when I'm using them as http_archives?

Tags: bazel, glog, gflags, bazel-cpp

I have a Bazel `WORKSPACE` that looks like this:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "com_github_gflags_gflags",
    sha256 = "34af2f15cf7367513b352bdcd2493ab14ce43692d2dcd9dfc499492966c64dcf",
    strip_prefix = "gflags-2.2.2",
    urls = ["https://github.com/gflags/gflags/archive/v2.2.2.tar.gz"],
)

http_archive(
    name = "com_github_google_glog",
    sha256 = "122fb6b712808ef43fbf80f75c52a21c9760683dae470154f02bddfc61135022",
    strip_prefix = "glog-0.6.0",
    urls = ["https://github.com/google/glog/archive/v0.6.0.zip"],
)
```

I can build targets with both gflags and glog just fine, but in order to see my log messages, I have to prefix `GLOG_logtostderr=1` in front of my commands, when I expected to be able to use `--logtostderr`.

I have found some similar questions out there on the Internet, but I wasn't able to get this working, perhaps because I'm new to Bazel. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001674/failure-compiling-glog-with-gflags-support-using-bazel) looks to be the closest question, but they aren't using `http_archive`, so they may have a bit more flexibility? I think my setup is pretty simple (setting up a new project with almost a blank slate), though, so I am hoping for a straightforward, easy solution.

I also tried setting `HAVE_LIB_GFLAGS` via a patch to glog, but that didn't seem to work (maybe set them in the wrong places) and I tried adding a `defines` attribute to my binary's target (though I'd rather the config be global to my workspace).

Thank you in advance for any ideas.

Comment: Hi I just wanted to follow up on this. Any ideas?